# How to change the font in a calplot plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I made a calendar heatmap using calplot. The documentation for calplot is here: https://calplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

I want to change the font of the title and labels, but do not know how to change the label font. I only managed to change the title font. Calplot is built upon matplotlib and it can pass on arguments to matplotlib.

First I exclusively focused on matplotlib and changed its font like this:

```
csfont = {'fontname':'Open Sans'}
hfont = {'fontname':'Open Sans'}

plt.title('title',**csfont)
plt.xlabel('xlabel', **hfont)
```

I then looked at the documentation of calplot and noticed the parameter `suptitle_kws`. I then tried to pass `csfont` as follows:

```
calplot.calplot(..., suptitle_kws=csfont)
```

And this correctly changed the title font. However, I also want to change the other fonts (of the weekdays and the colorbar). I don't know how to do this.